# Android bulkInsert Progress Values?

Tags: android, progressdialog, bulkinsert, progress, android-contentresolver

I am using the Content Resolver's **bulkInsert** Method to speed up insertion in an **AsyncTask**, its working great but i wanted to update the **ProgressDialog's** value in **publishProgress**.

Is this possible in **bulkinsert**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

1. Get the Length of the inserting Content.
2. Set the Value to the ProgessDialog.
3. Keep the Progress value as Global variable.

Do Progress updation method in `onPreExecuteMethod()`;

Comment: i set that from setMax. What about the updating +1 value after each insert? Is it even possible considering its a bulk insert